# Couchbase additional filters

Tags: couchbase

I have such problem with couchbase design: Query for view returns 40000 records. I need to add additional filter on them and get "top 100 order by".

I made such filtration/sorting in my application code this means I must fetch 40000 records from Couchbase (and this is time-consuming). Is there a way to execute filter/sort onto couchbase node (without fetching whole 4000 records to appserver)?

My data is touristic tours ie

```
{
   "OT": "tour",
   "dd": 20140720,
   "city": 1206,
   "hotel": 9656,
   "stars": 2,
   "resort": 23415,
   "country": 34,
   "price": 24139,
   "priceType": 1,
   "tickets": "QQYY",
   "nights": 5,
   "food": 4,
   "oper": 18,
   "adult": 1,
   "ch": 0,
   "ch1": 0,
   "ch2": 0,
   "ch3": 0,
   "avail": 1,
   "stop": "Q"
}
```

and i need to select top 10 cheapest tours from London to turkey between 20140622 and 20140710 in 4 or 5 stars hotel...

My view looks like:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.type==='json' && doc.OT==='tour'){
    emit(["A",doc.country,doc.city,doc.adult,doc.ch,doc.priceType,doc.dd,doc.price]);
    emit(["R" + doc.resort,doc.country,doc.city,doc.adult,doc.ch,doc.priceType,doc.dd,doc.price]);
  }
}
```

RESORT+COUNTRY+DEPARTURE_CITY+ADULT_COUNT+CHILD_COUNT+PRICE_TYPE+DEPARTURE_DATE allows me to select ~ 40000 records from 3000000+ (for DEPARTURE_DATE range) but sometimes (according user input) I still need to filter out them by Stars (stars IN (4,5) for example). Also view sorting is "BY Date,Price" this is'nt applicable, for example I got

```
20140101 110$ <- top but not cheapest
20140101 120$
20140102 100$ <- cheapest but not top
20140102 105$
```

At other side sometimes I also need to fetch N cheapest tours where DepartureDate BETWEEN x and Y and Price BETWEEN A and Z.
All those scenarios require additional filters to filter out from HUGE dataset (even high-selective VIEW as shown above still produce HUGE dataset in my case) and I do not want fetch  whole dataset to client (AppServer) for such processing... I realize processing on Couchbase nodes will consume more CPU on them but I prefer to add more Couchbase nodes to cluster...
**Anyway someone need to do this filtering work, I believe it's much more optimal to do it where data actually placed without additional network overhead...**

Comment: Add your current view code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Dimzon,

You can sort on the value of the key emitted by the view using the `descending` parameter. There is also a `limit` parameter that will restrict the number of responses you obtain per query.

Anon,
Andrew

Comment: this is not applicable :(